# Are heat emissions as bad as greenhouse gasses?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation, conservation-laws, equilibrium

Most of the technology we use generates excessive heat. Like cars, computers, smartphones, batteries etc... All of these needs to be cooled down in some way. Is all this extra heat adding to rising temperatures? Isn’t pursuing nuclear energy (fission or fusion) bad thing then? Even if it is clean energy. If energy doesn’t come from the sun, wouldn’t that automatically create imbalance in global temperature?

Comment: I think the reasoning is that all the solar energy received from the sun far outweighs that. For example, solar energy drives hurricanes and a hurricane has the energy of many thousands of nuclear bombs.

Comment: Here's another way to look at it.  Some of the sunlight that strikes the ground is reflected back to space "as is".  Installing solar cells to capture this sunlight will also slightly increase the heat flowing through the environment, because any electrical or mechanical work derived from those solar cells will eventually turn into heat.  However, as DKNguyen pointed out, the effect is very small.

Comment: I would like to know why people are suddenly posting questions that are asking why personal energy consumption is a bad thing if and only if that energy consumption does not come directly from solar cells or wind turbines.

Comment: See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/459462/to-what-extent-do-man-made-generators-of-heat-from-internal-sources-in-earths/459468

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we burn 1L of gasoline, which releases about 30 MJ of energy and about 2kg of CO2. We would like to estimate how much energy that CO2 will prevent from being radiated out into space before it is reabsorbed in the carbon cycle. Unfortunately this direct comparison is quite hard, so let me propose a different measure.

Instead lets imagine that we've built an enormous magic-glass column to contain our experiment (magic-glass is transparent to all frequencies of light), and just ask if that column is a 1 m^2 cross section how much we've changed the concentration of CO2 vs how much burning has increased the temperature.

Atmospheric pressure is about 10^5 N/m^2 so there is approximately 10^4 kg of air in the column. 0.04% (400ppm) of that is CO2 or about 4kg. So actually we've made a big increase in the amount of CO2 in the column, about a 50% increase.

Meanwhile the heat capacity of the column is about 100 MJ/degree K, so the burn only raised the temperature about 0.3 K. The effect of raising the CO2 concentration by 50% is excepted to be waaay larger, although estimating it requires detailed climate models.

I hope someone who actually studies climate science can tell me if these numbers are reasonable.

Comment: There are 1.32 x 10^18 kg of air on earth, so it would take a LOT of hydrocarbon burning to have the effect you are detailing.  Also, water vapor is the most important greenhouse gas, a lot of heat is transferred from the surface of the earth via convection, absolute humidity transfers heat and makes clouds which both block outgoing sunlight and increase albedo, there are many interactions between the atmosphere and ocean circulation, etc.  The climate is a very complicated system to mathematically model with confidence.

Comment: @DavidWhite to phrase my answer a different way, if you burned 1L of gasoline in each m^2 of the surface of the Earth you would warm the atmosphere 0.3K and increase the CO2 content by 50%. I agree, there will also be a lot of water released (about 1kg per L) and most of the heat will be absorbed by the ocean etc. Those caveats further support the point that the greenhouse effect is stronger, but it's a lot harder to quantify them.

Comment: I seriously doubt that you could find enough gasoline on earth to burn 1 L/m^2 of earth's surface, and if you could find that much gasoline and you lit it all off at the same time, no one would have to worry about global warming, as everyone would be incinerated.